# unit automat:the following signal(s) form a combinatorial loop

Tags: unit-testing, vhdl

I have some problems with this unit and I don't know why it's not working. The platform ISE Project Navigator gives me this error: `unit automat:the following signal(s) form a combinatorial loop`.I would like to receive some advice and if you can tell me how to resolve this problem.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.all;  
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.all;
entity automat is
    port(CLK,EN,SEN,MONED:in STD_LOGIC;
    COMP:STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);
    REN,MEN,ENR,IM_REST,REST,BILET,CLK_EN,RESET: out STD_LOGIC;
    S1,S2,com:out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0)
    );
end automat;
architecture arh_automat of automat is 
type STARE is(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J);
signal ST,NXST:STARE;
begin
    tranzitie:process(CLK,ST,EN,SEN,MONED,COMP) 
    begin 
        REN<='0';MEN<='0';clk_en<='0';RESET<='0';
        ENR<='0';IM_REST<='0';REST<='0';BILET<='0';
        S1<="00";S2<="00";com<="00";
        case ST is    
            when A=>NXST<=B;  
            com<="00";
                if(CLK'EVENT and CLK='1') then
                    if EN='1' then
                        ST<=B;
                    else
                        ST<=A; 
                    end if;
                END IF;
            when B=>NXST<=C ;
            RESET<='1'; 
            com<="01";
            if(CLK'EVENT and CLK='1') then
                    if EN='1' then
                        ST<=C;  
                    else
                        ST<=B;   
                    end if; 
                end if;
            when C=>NXST<=D; 
            REN<='1';
            CLK_EN<='1';
            com<="10";
            if(CLK'EVENT and CLK='1') then
                    if SEN ='1' then
                        ST<=D;          
                    else
                        ST<=C; 
                    end if; 
                    end if;
            when D=>NXST<=E ; 
                s1<="01";
                s2<="10"; 
                com<="10";
            if(CLK'EVENT and CLK='1') then
                    if MONED='1' then
                        ST<=E;
                    else        
                        ST<=F;
                end if;
            end if;
            when E=>NXST<=F; 
            com<="00";
            if(CLK'EVENT and CLK='1')  then
                ST<=F;                
            end if;
            when F=>NXST<=G ; 
            MEN<='1';
            com<="00";
            if(CLK'EVENT and CLK='1') then
                if COMP="010" or COMP="100" then
                    ST<=G;  
                else
                    ST<=C;
                end if;
            end if;
            when G=>NXST<=H; 
                    ENR<='1';
                    S1<="00";
                    S2<="11";
                    com<="00";
            if(CLK'EVENT and CLK='1') then
                if COMP="100" OR COMP="001" OR COMP="010" then
                    ST<=H;  
                    else
                    ST<=I;
                end if;
            END IF;
            when H=>NXST<=J; 
            REST<='1';
            BILET<='1';
            com<="00";
            if(CLK'EVENT and CLK='1') then   
            ST<=J;
            end if;
            when I=>NXST<=J;
                IM_REST<='1';
                BILET<='1';
                com<="00";
            if(CLK'EVENT and CLK='1') then  
                ST<=J;
            end if;
            when J=>NXST<=A;
            com<="00";
            if(CLK'EVENT and CLK='1') then
                ST<=A;  
                end if;
        end case;
    end process tranzitie;                                                                                                                                                                                                               
end arh_automat;
```

Comment: Which signals are those that form a combinatorial loop?  Please be specific.  Are there both ports of mode in and out involved in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which signals are forming the loop but your process & case construct are not written well.

Try splitting the combinatorial and synchronous signals into separate processes. Your clocking is messed up too. In the syncronous process, use just one "CLK'EVENT and CLK = '1'" statement with the case statement under it.

Answer (score 0):

A combinatorial loop is when you have the output of some combinatorial logic fed back into itself.  The most basic example I can think of is:

```
My_PROC : process(A)
begin
    A <= not A;
end process;
```

Its obviously not possible to synthesize this.
Its pretty difficult to figure out what's going on in your code but you need to look for a case where the output of some combinatorial logic is fed back into itself.  Like @lsf_design said, you should split up the combinatorial and clock synchronous logic.  I would recommend using the format described [here](http://vhdlguru.blogspot.com/2010/04/how-to-implement-state-machines-in-vhdl.html).

I would try to give your signals more descriptive names. Instead of using A, B, C, etc. for your state names, name them something that actually describes what that case does.

Comment: It's possible to synthesize such logic, when you're aware of what you're doing (e.g. [ring oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_oscillator)).

Comment: I see your point, that can be done at least physically.  How would a synthesis tool handle that though?  Normal timing analysis isn't going to work on that, so what kind of constraints would you use?
Either way, I'm pretty sure that's not what he's trying to do, haha.